# How to get the current date with Laravel Artisan?

Tags: date, unix, laravel, command-line, laravel-artisan

I want to get the current date with artisan using backup-manager/laravel.
I have tried to add this UNIX code but is not working:

```
$(date "+\%X")
```

How do you get the current date with Artisan?

Thank you.

Comment: Tell us more about what u want to do. u need to pass the time to artisan command or what?

Comment: yes, the command is this one:
`php artisan db:backup --database=mysql --destination=dropbox --destinationPath=mybackup --compression=gzip`
So I want to add the current time at `--destinationPath`

Comment: Remove the backslash?

Comment: Thank you  @glennjackman, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @glennjackman said, the correct syntax is:

`$(date "+%X")`

So the correct command is:

`php artisan db:backup --database=mysql --destination=dropbox --destinationPath=mybackup --compression=gzip So I want to add the current time at --destinationPath`